# Testing Command with Xamarin.Forms (MVVM)

Tags: xamarin.forms, nunit

So, I've been having trouble testing the following scenario:

```
ICommand LoginCommand;

public LoginViewModel()
{
    LoginCommand = new Command(async () => await LoginCommandAction());
}

private async Task LoginCommandAction()
{
    var response = await _tokenService.GetToken(_user, _password, token);
}
```

Thats my ViewModel. Now, in my ViewModel test, I want to able to call an `execute` on my LoginCommand and **await** the GetToken to finish so I can assert its results.

I've tried just calling the `execute()` but the test finishes before the call.

I've also tried:

```
public async Task TestMethod() =>  await Task.Run(() => Vm.LoginCommand.Execute(null));
```

But that didn't work too. I believe that I have to return something on my **Action**, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

Test something like that:

```
public ICommand LoginCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () => 
        {
            await LoginCommandAction();
        });
    }
}

async Task LoginCommandAction()
{
    await _tokenService.GetToken(_user, _password, token).ContinueWith((arg) => 
    {
        if(arg.IsCompleted)
        {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure the BindingContext of your view is the correct one and that your binding has the following form in your .xaml:

```
Command = "{Binding LoginCommand}"
```

Comment: Same thing, wharever is inside the IsCompleted is never called because  the test finishes before that.

Comment: Maybe the type of the return of GetToken could be Task<bool>, then you could write: if(await _tokenService.GetToken()){...}

Answer (score 0):

You can not use await keyword for ICommand.Execute method. If you want to test your login operation, first change LoginCommandAction's method access modifier as public and call LoginCommandAction method from your TestMethod.